# SQL stored procedure to update a table column by calculating the difference from 2 other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in SQL Server that are exactly the same. I am trying to write a stored procedure to get the value of 2 columns from 2 tables and update the 3rd table with the difference. These are the 3 tables:

Current

Proposed

Final

I am passing in rfds_processing_id. It is similar to an order number and contains multiple rows, so matching has to be done on rfds_processing_id, type, sector, and position.

I need to match every row from the 3 tables and then subtract the value of Current.qty from Final.qty and update the Proposed.qty with the difference. It also needs to update Proposed.model with the value of Final.model (when Proposed.qty > 0). Currently it is setting every row to the same value. I'm assuming I need to loop through the rows. What should that look like?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateProposedAntennas]
(
  @rfds_processing_id uniqueidentifier = null,
  @id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE P 
  SET qty = (F.qty - C.qty) , model = F.model
  FROM Proposed_Antenna P
  INNER JOIN Final_Antenna F
      ON P.rfds_processing_id = F.rfds_processing_id
  INNER JOIN Current_Antenna C
      ON F.rfds_processing_id = C.rfds_processing_id
  WHERE 
      F.rfds_processing_id = C.rfds_processing_id 
      AND F.sector = C.sector 
      AND F.type = C.type
      AND F.position = C.position   
  RETURN
END
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample input data and desired output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateProposedAntennas]
(
  @rfds_processing_id uniqueidentifier = null,
  @id uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE P 
SET P.qty = F.qty - C.qty 
   ,P.model = CASE WHEN Proposed.qty > 0 THEN F.model ELSE NULL END
FROM Proposed_Antenna P
INNER JOIN Final_Antenna F
      ON F.rfds_processing_id = P.rfds_processing_id AND F.sector = P.sector AND F.type = P.type AND F.position = P.position
INNER JOIN Current_Antenna C
      ON C.rfds_processing_id = P.rfds_processing_id AND C.sector = P.sector AND C.type = P.type AND C.position = P.position
  RETURN
END
```

I highly recommend you to create a [UID] column in all three of your tables - the unique identifier case can be generated as below, the generated key is of `varbinary` type which is far better than string comparison in joins

```
select [UID] = HashBytes('MD5',rfds_processing_id+type+sector+position)
```

Comment: Wow, lots of good information! I will create the UID column for each and try this.

Comment: Are you saying I can remove the Inner Joins if adding the UID columns and the select UID statement?

Comment: You can't remove the joins, however you no longer have to use multiple AND for Joins, instead of `F.rfds_processing_id = P.rfds_processing_id AND F.sector = P.sector AND F.type = P.type AND F.position = P.position` you could just use `F.UID = P.UID`